# Apigee push example: Device not chosen for sample

Tags: ios, apigee

I am starting off with apigee. I tried running the push test example. I created an app called Push Test and a notifier in the portal. When I launch the app on my iPad, I see just a white screen with the following lines spit out to the console:

```
2014-01-17 00:58:07.601 Push Test[1087:60b] setting up app services connection
2014-01-17 00:58:07.606 Push Test[1087:60b] apigee: dataClient created
2014-01-17 00:58:07.677 Push Test[1087:60b] apigee: monitoringClient created
2014-01-17 00:58:07.680 Push Test[1087:60b] done launching
Jan 17 00:58:08 bobs-iPad com.Apigee.system[1087] <Notice>: -[ApigeeMonitoringClient startMonitoring] Device not chosen for sample
Jan 17 00:58:08 bobs-iPad Push Test[1087] <Notice>: -[ApigeeMonitoringClient startMonitoring] INIT_AGENT
```

That's it. How do I fix this? I think I am missing something obviously simple. I did make the necessary changes in the AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: What name did you give the notifier in the App Services UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the UI has not been set up for iPad (the MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard is empty). Can you run it on an iPhone or iPod Touch as an interim solution?

Let me explain the "Device not chosen for sample". In the Apigee portal, you can configure the "Sampling Rate" to be a percentage. By default, it's set to 100%. You can lower this. Let's say that you set it to 30%. This would mean that, on average, only 30% of your users would be chosen to participate in the sample. Which sample? The sampling for app monitoring. If you aren't interested in app monitoring, then you can ignore this entirely.

App monitoring is independent of push notifications, BTW. It's possible to use one without the other.

If you're interested in seeing where the "Device not chosen for sample" comes from, have a look at [ApigeeMonitoringClient.m (github)](https://github.com/apigee/apigee-ios-sdk/blob/master/source/Classes/Services/ApigeeMonitoringClient.m) lines 745-764